# Preciso de um menu cujo sub-menu apareça acima do menu

Tags: html5, css3

Descupas pela falta de informação: no exemplo do código abaixo, quando se passa o mouse sobre o menu, o sub-menu apare abaixo do menu, não sei como fazer para aparecer acima do menu, quem souber e quiser ajudar, eu agradeço.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/infor.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>MenuEx</title>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
/*Formatação*/
.menuhorizontal2{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
height: 30px;
}
.menuhorizontal2 ul{ 
list-style: none;
}
.menuhorizontal2 li{ 
width: 80px;
padding:0px;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
display: inline;
float: left;
border-left: #999999 thin solid;
}
.menuhorizontal2 li ul{
display: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 0;
}

                                /*nível inferior do menu com display: none*/
.menuhorizontal2 a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 7px;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 400;
} 

                                /* formatação da âncora e área clicável*/
.menuhorizontal2 li:hover ul, li.hover ul{
display: block;
}

.menuhorizontal2 li:hover ul, li.over ul{
display: block;
}


</style>

<ul class="menuhorizontal2">
<li><a href="#">Menu_1</a>
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#">SubM_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubM_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubM_3</a></li>
    </ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="#">Menu_2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubM_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubM_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubM_3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Você poderia elaborar mais como você espera que esse menu seja e o quer dizer com subir? Você quer fazer uma navbar?

Comment: Por favor, _esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página [ask] para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta._ Pode começar compartilhando o que você já tentou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muka seque um exemplo que fiz para vc dar uma estudada, é um exemplo simples, porém fácil de entender. Usei `display:flex` para deixa-lo mais responsivo, mas é bem tranquilo de entender. Usei `position:fixed` para pregar ele na base da página, e um `top` negativo com `transition` para faze-lo subir no `:hover`

Veja o exemplo e estude o código. []´s que acho que pode te ajudar no futuro...

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 25%;
    height: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    background-color: turquoise;
}
.sub {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc(100% + 2px);
    height: 2rem;
    top: 2rem;
    background-color: tomato;
    transition: top 300ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}
.item:hover .sub{
    top: -2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
<div class="item">
    <a href="">item</a>
    <div class="sub">
        <a href="">sub</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="">item</a>
    <div class="sub">
        <a href="">sub</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="">item</a>
    <div class="sub">
        <a href="">sub</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="">item</a>
    <div class="sub">
        <a href="">sub</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve procurar por **menu** e **submenu**, assim você encontra várias formas de criar, desde com css puro ou com algum plugin jquery (o mais famoso e fácil é o **bootstrap**)

Eu tenho um código com menu e submenu que tenho faz um tempo, peguei de um lugar mas já esqueci qual é, mas sempre tenho aqui comigo. Esse é um menu puro:

```css
/* Reset CSS */
*, *:after, *:before{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
/* Fundo do menu */
.menu{
  background: #000;
}
/* Remove as bolinhas do lado das listas */
.menu .menu-list, .menu .sub-menu{
  list-style: none;
}
/* Configura todos os links do nosso menu */
.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing:0.2em;
}
/* Faz os <li>s ficarem na horizontal */
.menu > .menu-list > li{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
/* Configura os links do menu principal */
.menu > .menu-list > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #000;
}
/* Configura o fundo do menu principal quando com mouse hover */
.menu > .menu-list > li:hover a {
  background: #444;
}
/* Mostra o submenu no evento de mouse hover */
.menu > .menu-list > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
/* Configura o estilo do submenu */
.menu > .menu-list > li > .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 5px;
  background: blue;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
/* Configura os links do submenu */
.menu > .menu-list > li > .sub-menu > li > a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
/* Clearfix para o menu */
.menu:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Agora, a questão de posicionar no **bottom**, te aconselho o **Bootstrap**, inclusive tem uma propriedade de **navbar** dele que possui uma **class** que já te posiciona ele fixamente no inferior da sua página.

Comment: Só que ele quer na base da página com o sub-menu aparecendo pra cima.... O inverso do seu exemplo...

Comment: Pois é, por isso recomendei o bootstrap, é bem mais facil que montar esse código grande, só muda 3 4 linhas e já se tem um navbar com dropup e fixado no bottom da página responsivamente